# Is There a Concise Way To Achieve Conditional Pluralization of TimeSpan Format?

Tags: c#, datetime, format, timespan

I have `TimeSpan` object that tracks calculation times. This `TimeSpan` can range from seconds to days. I currently have a quite verbose method in place to give me a string from the `TimeSpan` that represents the `TimeSpan` in a long form; for example:

```
3 Days 13 Hours 1 Minute 52 Seconds
```

When the `TimeSpan` is less than `1` second, I display the `Milliseconds` property instead. The code for this is simplistic but is quite verbose as I stated above. Is there a concise way to achieve this similar to `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy hhmmssffff")`? Below is my current code:

```
public static string GetLongTime(TimeSpan t) {
    string result = string.Empty;
    if (t.Days > 0) {
        if (t.Days == 1) result = "1 Day";
        else result = $"{t.Days} Days";
    } else if (t.TotalMilliseconds < 1000) {
        if (t.Milliseconds > 0)
            result = $"{t.Milliseconds}ms";
    } else {
        if (t.Hours > 0) {
            if (t.Hours == 1) result += "1 Hour ";
            else result += $"{t.Hours} Hours ";
        }
        if (t.Minutes > 0) {
            if (t.Minutes == 1) result += "1 Minute ";
            else result += $"{t.Minutes} Minutes ";
        }
        if (t.Seconds > 0) {
            if (t.Seconds == 1) result += "1 Second ";
            else result += $"{t.Seconds } Seconds ";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Just as with `DateTime`, the `TimeSpan` object has a [custom format list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings); however, their example list displays strings with the good ol' fashioned `(s)` appendage:

```
  TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(1, 12, 23, 62);
  Console.WriteLine("Time of Travel: {0:%d} day(s)", duration);
  Console.WriteLine("Time of Travel: {0:dd\\.hh\\:mm\\:ss} days", duration);
```

> Time of Travel: 1 day(s)
>
> Time of Travel: 01.12:24:02 days

This isn't really what I'm looking for. I've also looked into some related posts here on StackOverflow, and as one user pointed out in a comment, they are good resources. Overall, these aren't the solutions I'm looking for either as I am mostly in high hopes of something incredibly concise such as:

```
return t.ToString("d Day?s");
```

Granted the above is just pseudo and wouldn't actually do more than:

> 3 Day?s

Some of the related posts have promise to refactor my code; for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840120/timespan-formatting/840177#840177) that recommends the conditional assignment operator:

```
string result = string.Empty;
if (t.Days > 0)
    return $"{t.Days} {(t.Days > 1 ? "Days " : "Day ")}";
else if (t.TotalMilliseconds < 1000) {
    if (t.Milliseconds > 0)
        return $"{t.Milliseconds}ms";
} else {
    if (t.Hours > 0)
        result += $"{t.Hours} {(t.Hours > 1 ? "Hours " : "Hour ")}";
    if (t.Minutes > 0)
        result += $"{t.Minutes} {(t.Minutes > 1 ? "Minutes " : "Minute ")}";
    if (t.Seconds > 0)
        result += $"{t.Seconds} {(t.Seconds > 1 ? "Seconds " : "Second ")}";
}
return result;
```

Though this shortens the code, it doesn't exactly make it look the cleanest either (especially to new developers). Which is also in line with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689468/how-to-produce-human-readable-strings-to-represent-a-timespan?rq=1) that recommends using a `SortedList` of the proper formats; however, I agree with the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1568959/michael-mankus) on that post; *Your code does take some time to follow. That's the only thing I'm not in love with.*.

Is there a way to achieve conditional pluralization within the format string; or, is there a more simplistic and concise approach compared to what I have above?

Comment: The common code could be put into a method `string Pluralize(int amount, string unit)`

Comment: Have you thought about `$"{t.Days} Day{(t.Days>1?"s":"")}"` ?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840177/8061994). Something along these lines may be what you need. It is similar to what @Fildor suggested above.

Comment: I've thought about slimming it down with the conditional assignment operator `?:`, definitely a good point. I'll make sure I add the posts I've looked at here to my post so that future readers understand all of the options I have looked into.

Comment: It's not clear for me what format you're looking for: *Is there a concise way to achieve this similar to* `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy hhmmssffff")`. This is quite different from `3 Days 13 Hours 1 Minute 52 Seconds`. The language should be considered (`ddMMyyyy` is not the *Invariant* format)? If you're just looking for a "shorter" code, I can post a *sample* and you can see if it fits.

Comment: @Jimi The quote of `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy hhmmssffff")` was a basic example of the way I would ***like*** to be able to format the string. I'll be more than happy to look at your example. Shorter code is a bonus, but readability will always prevail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a shorter method. Readability here is a matter of perspective :)

Some examples, to see if this meets the requirements.

`TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(3, 4, 10, 25);`
`=> 3 Days 4 Hours 10 Minutes 25 Seconds`

`TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 700);`
`=> 700ms`

`TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 1, 700);`
`=> 2 Hours 1 Second`

`TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1, 1);`
`=> 1 Day 1 Hour 1 Minute 1 Second`

---

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan([Some time span]);

string[] TFormat = new[] {
    (ts.Days > 1 ? ts.Days + " Days" : (ts.Days == 1 ? "1 Day" : "")),
    (ts.Hours > 1 ? " "+ ts.Hours + " Hours" : (ts.Hours == 1 ? " 1 Hour" : "")),
    (ts.Minutes > 1 ? " " + ts.Minutes + " Minutes" : (ts.Minutes == 1 ? " 1 Minute" : "")),
    (ts.Seconds > 1 ? " " + ts.Seconds + " Seconds" : (ts.Seconds == 1 ? " 1 Second" : "")),
    (ts.TotalMilliseconds < 1000 ? $"{ts.TotalMilliseconds }ms" : "")
};

Console.WriteLine($"{TFormat[0]}{TFormat[1]}{TFormat[2]}{TFormat[3]}{TFormat[4]}".TrimStart());
```

Comment: This is a very clean example (though still utilizing the conditional assignment), I didn't really think to use an array for this. +1

Comment: The answer itself is well written as is the code; I just think the nested conditional assignment `a = b > 1 ? c : b == 1 ? d : e` is a bit much (could be confusing to newer developers).

Comment: @davisj1691  Allright, I'll see what I can do for those developers.

Comment: no need to further modify your answer; I am essentially accounting for the junior developers in my work environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in TimeSpan format specifier in .NET which would make this possible.

However, I've implemented this functionality as I needed it before. It's available in my free and open-source [utility library](https://github.com/adams85/common/blob/e7527eaaef7f8d57a12bbf6ac9f5050a5f49bbf0/source/Karambolo.Common/DateTimeUtils.cs#L53). It's published under MIT license so you're allowed to copy the code or include the library in your project.

**Usage** (when choosing the latter option)

Install the NuGet package. Type the following in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Karambolo.Common
```

Then you can convert a *TimeSpan* value using the *ToTimeReference* extension method like this.

```
using System;
using Karambolo.Common;
using Karambolo.Common.Localization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ts = new TimeSpan(3, 13, 1, 52);
        Console.WriteLine(ts.ToTimeReference(4, "{0}", "now", "{0}", DefaultTextLocalizer.Instance));
    }
}
```

The code above prints:

```
3 days 13 hours 1 minute 52 seconds
```

The *ToTimeReference* overload I used in the sample code gives you full control over the formatting of the output. The last argument is a delegate which is responsible for specifying the format of the time interval strings (like "day", "hour", etc.) E.g. it can be used to localize the output of the function.

Comment: Though this is useful and indeed a good answer, I am unable to utilize this as I am unable to use any external libraries. I've thought about adding this to all of my posts, maybe I should start doing that. Good answer none the less.

Comment: @davisj1691 You are free to copy and modify the necessary parts of the source code if you don't want to include the whole package.